# Awk processing and parsing

Tags: parsing, awk

Trying to use **STRICTLY** `awk` to solve a little issue and I can't wrap myself around the solution:

```
# more connections
0x828ac008 127.0.0.1:5152            127.0.0.1:1387              2000
0x82cc28f8 10.4.4.63:1435            10.4.4.72:22                1132
0x82ec1de0 10.4.4.63:1524            50.28.90.36:8080            3248

# awk -F":" '/[0-9]/{print $1,$2}' connections | awk '!/^127/{print "nslookup "$4}'
nslookup 127.0.0.1
nslookup 10.4.4.72
nslookup 50.28.90.36
```

I am looking for a streamlined method to just parse out anything aside from loopbacks `^127` and the `10.` addresses in my netblock. Yes, I know I can use `sed`, `grep`, `cut`, etc, but I'm hoping to see how someone else would do this in `awk`. Its more of a learning curve/a-ha! thing

Clarifying: Output would omit `10.x.x.x` and `127.x.x.x`

Output would be

```
nslookup 50.28.90.36
```

I tried `awk` `!/^127\.|^10\./` but I couldn't get it to ignore the values.

Comment: Do you need values from column 2 or column 3 or both (counting space separated columns)?

Answer (score 5):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F "[: ]+" 'NR>1 && !($4 ~ /^(127|10)\./){print "nslookup", $4}' connections
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
nslookup  50.28.90.36
```

Comment: Your command doesn't print anything. It's not `$2`. It's the second IP, and the OP wants the literal `nslookup`, not `$1`. I think it's better iddea to change the `FS` to `-F'[:[:space:]]+'` and play with `$4`.

Comment: @Birei: Thanks mate for very nice comment. I misread the question and thought OP is trying to match IP in column 2. Edited the question now.

Comment: anubhava the edited version worked. Going to study what its doing now

Comment: Much better now :-) I don't know if `NR>1` is neccesary. Perhaps the comment at the beginning was added here by the OP, but it's easy for him decide to remove it.

Comment: Yes `NR>1` wasn't necessary. OP, please feel free to take it out if first line is not a comment as per your example.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 2):

[Anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709275/970195) offers a great solution by setting **Field Separators**. Here is an alternate way of doing it using the default `FS`:

#### Using `split` function:

```
awk '$3!~/^(127|10)/{split($3,ip,/:/);print "nslookup",ip[1]}' connections
```

#### Using `sub` function:

```
awk '$3!~/^(127|10)/{sub(/:.*/,"",$3);print "nslookup", $3}' connections
```

Also a **`bash`** way of doing it:

```
while read -ra lines; do 
  [[ ! ${lines[2]} =~ "^(127|10).*" ]] && echo "nslookup ${lines[2]%:*}"; 
done < connections
```